# How can i make the right top icon open new activity instead of showing item?

Tags: android, android-layout

So, i have this

[image]

And here how i set it.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

My `menu->main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

and here is my `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");


    toolbar.setOverflowIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_notifications));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView =  findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

well, it's a default thing, For now when i click the bell icon it will showing the `item` from `menu.xml`. **But, what i want is , when i click the bell icon, it will open new activity instead of showing the `item` from `menu.xml`**

How can i achieve that ?

I wonder why my question `marked as duplicate` ? My question is, **How can i make the right top icon open new activity instead of showing item?**

Not

**How to open activity from menu item**

Comment: Put main.xml file from menu.

Comment: @Abhishek ah, i forget. sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `onOptionsItemSelected()` method

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent = new (CurrentActivity.class, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read this, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/bell"
            android:visible="true"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="bell"/>
    </menu>
```

Add below code in your activity.

```
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)     {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_settings:

                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityName.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```